# Why do I have a different session_id on each page of the website?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, php-5.6

I created a php (MVC) website version 5.6.30. I added session_start() in the index.php but every time I change page this changes session_id(), going bad the stored variables.

this is the index.php file that creates the connection to the database and creates a controller based on the received url.

```
    <?php
        chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
        require_once __DIR__ .'/../core/Domanda.php';
        session_start();
        session_id();
        require_once __DIR__.'/../helpers/class.smtp.php';
        require_once __DIR__.'/../helpers/class.phpmailer.php';


        require_once __DIR__.'/../DB/DBPDO.php';

        require_once __DIR__ .'/../DB/DbFactory.php';

        require_once __DIR__.'/../config/tfpdf.php';

        require_once __DIR__.'/../config/PDF.php';

        require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/controllers/PostController.php';
    ecc..

$controller->display();
```

this is the controller.php file that determines which method and executes the various calls using the post model

```
     class PostController extends BaseController{
          protected $layout = 'layout/index2.tpl.php';
  public $content ='Controller';

 protected $conn;
          protected $Post ;

          public function __construct(PDO $conn) {
         $this->conn=$conn;
            $this->Post = new Post($conn);

          }

public function display(){
    require  $this->layout;
  } 


          public function getArticles(){ //home
            global $page;
            $posts = $this->Post->all($page);
            $evento = $this->Post->allPosts(1);
            $articoliTOT = $this->Post->countArticoli();

            $this->content =  viewSidebar('articoliHome', compact('posts'), $this->sidebar,$this->lingua, compact('evento'), $articoliTOT->total);
          }
```

this is the model file that queries the database

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use \PDO;
use \PDF;
use \PHPMailer;
class Post extends Base{


    public function __construct(PDO $conn) {
        parent::__construct($conn);
    }

    public function all($page){
        $result = [];
        $RECORDS_PER_PAGE=RECORDS_PER_PAGE+1;
        $start= $RECORDS_PER_PAGE * ($page -1);
          if($start< 0) {
              $start = 0;
          }

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM articoli_'.$_SESSION['lan'].' WHERE tipo >=3 ORDER BY art_data DESC LIMIT ? , ?';
        $stm = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->bindParam(2, $RECORDS_PER_PAGE, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->execute();

        if($stm && $stm->rowCount()){

            $result =  $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }

        return $result;

    }
```

functions.php

```
function viewSidebar($view, array $data = [], $sidebar, $lingua, array $dataSB = [], $articoliTOT){ //5
  global $page;
  extract($data);
  extract($dataSB);
  ob_start();
  require __DIR__ .'/../app/views/'.$view.'.tpl.php';
  $output =  ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $output;
}
```

index2.php

```
<?php
require_once (__DIR__.'/../layout/header.tpl.php');
require_once (__DIR__.'/../layout/nav.tpl.php');
?>
     <div id="contenuto" class="row mx-3 my-3">

    <?=$this->content?>
  </div>


</div>

<?php
require_once (__DIR__.'/../layout/footer.tpl.php');?>
```

Why do I have a different session_id on each page of the website?

Answer (score -1):

Place the session_start as the top of your file, there should be no ouputs before session initialization, and i dont know what is included from `require_once __DIR__ .'/../core/Domanda.php';`

Comment: There's no need to re declare session_start() since it is declared on the main file.

Comment: am not asking you to redeclare session_start, am telling you to move it up before any outputs

Comment: In your index.php after the php opening tag next should be session_start()